# Why did the translator use ゴナラ here?

Tags: translation, katakana

I've got a copy of "オ・ヤサシ巨人BFG", Taeko Nakamura's translation of the famous children's book by Roald Dahl, [The BFG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_BFG).

The story concerns a friendship between a little girl named Sophie and a friendly giant (the titular BFG). In one chapter, the BFG introduces Sophie to a delicious fizzy beverage, called "frobscottle". This drink has bubbles which flow down instead of up, and make the drinker fart in a way that propels them around the room (yep, it's a pretty silly story).

In the original, this action is called a **whizzpopper** (a made-up word), and in Nakamura's translation, it is **ゴナラ**.

My question: **Where does this "ゴナラ" come from?** There are no results for it in http://jisho.org/, and various google search terms fail to turn up anything relevant for me.

I would suspect that it is simply a made-up word, except that Nakamura's translations of Dahl's other made-up words all have some structure / come from existing words, e.g.:

- "Frobscottle" (the fizzy beverage) is 泡立ちエキス, "bubbles extract".
- "Snozzcumbers" (unpleasant tasting vegetables eaten by giants) are お化けキュウリ, "ghost cucumber".

So, is ゴナラ pure onomatopoeia / a fabrication just for this story, or does it have some external meaning that I am missing?

Comment: +1 for reading The BFG in Japanese! What does the (Japanese) BFG say about people from Greece tasting greasy?

Comment: He says "グリシアのニンゲンマメは脂っこすぎる", with furigana over both **グリシア** and **脂っこ** saying "グリース". That quote also shows how the BFG calls people ニンゲンマメ, which took me a little while to get, until I realized it's 人間豆 = human beans!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd guess it's just a play on おなら (fart).

Comment: And THAT's what I was missing. Thank you :)

Comment: Where does the ゴ come from?

Comment: @phoenixheart6 Maybe a play on words by replacing the お by ご (as 御 can be read both お and ご)...?

Comment: @user1205935 maybe...but the お isn't the polite 御 but the entire reading of the kanji 屁 (indicated by both [jisho](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E3%81%8A%E3%81%AA%E3%82%89&eng=&dict=edict) and [tangorin](http://tangorin.com/general/%E3%81%8A%E3%81%AA%E3%82%89)).

Comment: @phoenixheart6 That may be so, but there are no rules for plays on words... I figure it was 屁 -> おなら -> 御なら -> ごなら -> ゴナラ, although this reasoning is probably too explicit to be taken seriously.

Comment: True. I guess this is just one long way of me say, "I don't get it!"

Comment: Yeah, I like the 御 = o or go theory. That was my first thought when I read SomethingJapanese's answer - that おなら was reanalyzed as polite prefix o + nara for the sake of the joke.

Comment: I was thinking of the o/go prefix, too. =P  But I didn't know for sure and I thought I could be missing something else, so I didn't mention it.  Nice to know I'm not alone in that theory. ^_^  My other theory is that it might simply be some kind of onomatopoeic syllable.